# MultipleCheckbox form alignment

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that displays a Django multiple checkbox form using bootstrap.  I'm having difficulty getting the choices in the form to line up vertically - some of the options with longer labels are skewed relative to the other options. I want the form to display in the center of the `div` but I want all of the choices to line up nicely.  In the picture you can see the first choice is not aligned with the next two options.

[image]

My form looks like this:

```
class SCSelectForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    arg_list = kwargs.pop('sc_arg_list')
    section_label = kwargs.pop('sc_section_label')
    if kwargs.pop('all_true')==True:
        initial = [c[0] for c in arg_list]
    else:
        initial = None
    super(SCSelectForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['sc_ID'].choices=arg_list
    self.fields['sc_ID'].label=section_label
    self.fields['sc_ID'].initial=initial

  sc_ID = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
form_fileoptions = SCSelectForm(sc_arg_list=file_list,sc_section_label="",all_true=True)
forms_dict = {'fileoptions':form_fileoptions}

return render(request,'InterfaceApp/FileProcessor.html',forms_dict)
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<div class="row pad_forms">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {% bootstrap_form fileoptions %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Sounds like bootstrap_form is a custom template tag you have. Can you also post the html content of that template tag? There might be something strange about it.

Comment: @ShangWang I can't.  It's part of the bootstrap_toolkit library that I installed and am using.

Comment: If that's the case, please edit your post to use `django-bootstrap-toolkit` as the tag instead of `bootstrap`, people who have more experience might be able to see that(I couldn't edit it as I don't have enough reputation).